# Infer function return type from React component props

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Given the following function component, is there a way to declare that `onChange`'s `value` parameter must match the type of `value` passed to the component props?

```
function MyCheckbox({value} : {value: number|string}): React.ReactElement {
    const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, value: number|string) => {
        // Do something
    }

    return (
        <input type={"checkbox"} value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e, value)} />
    )
}
```

Similarly, what if I wanted some kind of `getValue()` function. Could I declare that if `MyCheckbox` was passed a `string` value, `getValue()` would return a `string`, and if `MyCheckbox` was passed a `number` value, then `getValue()` would return a `number`?

Comment: Make the function generic

Comment: TS Generics only seem to allow me to change a function's output based on the function's input. But here, I want to change a function's input based on a component's input. So, I'm not sure how to do that with Generics.

Comment: I meant, make the component function generic, and then refer to the generic type inside of it